# Please what is the _simpleStorageIndex and the _simpleStorageNumber in the function Sfstore

Tags: blockchain

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "./SimpleStorage.sol"; 

contract StorageFactory {

     SimpleStorage public simpleStorage;
    SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;
    
    function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
         simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
        simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
    }
    
    function sfStore(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex, uint256 _simpleStorageNumber) public {
        // Address 
        // ABI 
        // SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex])).store(_simpleStorageNumber);
        simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex].store(_simpleStorageNumber);
    }
    
    function sfGet(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex) public view returns (uint256) {
        // return SimpleStorage(address(simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex])).retrieve();
        return simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex].retrieve();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_simpleStorageIndex`: This is an integer parameter that represents the index of an item in the `simpleStorageArray`. It specifies which instance of the SimpleStorage contract you want to interact with. Each index in the array corresponds to a specific instance of the `SimpleStorage` contract.

`_simpleStorageNumber`: This is an integer parameter that represents the value you want to set in the specified instance of the `SimpleStorage` contract. It's the new value you want to store in the selected instance.

When you call the `sfStore` function, you need to provide two arguments: the index of the `SimpleStorage` contract you want to interact with and the new value you want to set in that contract. The function will then update the value in the selected `SimpleStorage` contract based on these parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful